# Is there a Reactive way to Validate Form Fields in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-validator

I have a Spring Boot/Webflux project and would like to set a validation error if a username already exists, with a friendly message. However, if I make a non-blocking call to the database in the `validate(Object target, Errors errors)` method then it's not clear what to do with the returned Mono. The only workaround I found was to use the non-reactive database driver to check for existence, which at least doesn't require calling block() directly. Any other suggestions?

Comment: can you provide code samples, your question is not clear !

Comment: I guess I'm just looking for a Reactive version of Spring's org.springframework.validation.Validator interface